# .sh script to install vscode and newrelic

Tags: bash, shell, admin

I am using FAI to make a custom Debian installer. I am trying to make a script to install vscode and newrelic.

```
wget https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-deb-x64
sudo apt install ./code_1.74.2-1671533413_amd64.deb
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
sudo apt update
sudo apt install code
```

Could I have help on installing the newrelic monitoring tool for Debian and improve the VS Code download?
Thank you!

I already tried the vs code install script and it did not work.

Comment: What does "it did not work" mean ?

Comment: A Stack Overflow question needs to be about a narrow, specific problem -- _one particular_ place you got stuck writing this script yourself, clearly identifying and reproducing that particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and try these to install VS Code:

1. wget -O code-latest.deb 'https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-deb-x64'
2. sudo apt install ./code-latest.deb
3. rm code-latest.deb [to delete the installer]
4. code [type this to run VS Code directly from your terminal]

I hope this helps!

Regards